# Prove: $T:V \to V$ is bijective if and only if $T$ is injective.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I know that if $T$ is bijective then $T$ is injective.

But how to prove when $T$ is injective, then $T$ is bijective?

I know that that $R(T)$ is a subspace of $V$, and for each vector in $R(T)$, let's say $u$ , there is a $v$ in $V$ that $T(v)=u$. But, what's next? I don't know how to prove $R(T) =V$.

Am I on the right track? Thanks

Comment: are you assuming V is finite dimensional?

Comment: I double checked the question, yes, V is a finite dimensional  vector space

Comment: It holds only when the space is finite dimensional. Then its also equivalent to surjectivity.

Comment: This follows immediately from the dimension theorem of linear maps, i.e. $\dim(V)=\dim(\ker(T))+\dim(\text{im}(T))$ and  the fact that $T$ is injective if and only if $\dim(\ker(T))=0$. Use this theorem wisely, it's a powerful tool!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true if you assume $V$ is a finite $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ dimensional vector space i.e. $V$ has a basis set of $n$ vectors $B = \{b_1, \ldots, b_n\}$. You also need that $T : V \to V$ is linear. Otherwise, the statement is just false: take $V = \mathbb{R}$ and $T(x) = e^x$. This is an injection that is not a surjection.

Now if $T : V \to V$ is linear, consider the set $T_B = \{T(b_n), \ldots, T(b_n)\}$. $T$ is injective and $B$ and $T_B$ are finite sets; so $T_B$ has exactly $n$ vectors also. Next, using linearity, you can show that $T_B$ is linearly independent because $B$ is. So, $T_B$ forms a basis for $V$ and any $v \in V$ can be written as
$$
v = \alpha_1 T(b_1) + \cdots + \alpha_n T(b_n) = T(\alpha_1 b_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n b_n)
$$ demonstrating the surjectivity of $T$.

**P.S.** This fact is not necessarily true for infinite dimensional vector spaces. The set of all infinite real sequences $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is a real vector space and the shift map $\sigma : \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ given by
$$
\sigma : \langle x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots \rangle \mapsto \langle 0, x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots \rangle
$$ is injective and linear. But it is not surjective: it misses sequences with non-zero first elements.

Comment: I am actually not sure if T is linear or not.my question handout isn't giving any extra information other than above. Is it possible to prove it while T is not specified as a linear transformation?

Comment: You need linearity because otherwise, the statement is false. Consider $V = \mathbb{R}$ and $T(x) = e^x$ for example. It is injective but is not bijective because it misses every non-positive number.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right, We have to assume T is linear to prove it. But how to prove T(B) is linearly independent? which property you are using?

Comment: @DesiredOB linearity of the map $T$ is used. If you have $\alpha_1 T(b_1) + \cdots \alpha_n T(b_n) = 0$, then by linearity $T(\alpha_1 b_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n b_n) = 0$. But $T(0) = 0$ also. So by injectivity what must be true?

Comment: So $α_1b_1+⋯+α_nb_n$ =0, and 0 is in V, so 0*B = 0, and by injectivity $α_1=...a_n=0$ is the only solution for $α_1T(b_1)+⋯+α_nt(b_n)=0$, which means linearly independence?

Comment: Not quite, injectivity of $T$ is used to get $\alpha_1 b_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n b_n = 0$ first because $0$ is the only value mapped to $0$ by $T$. Then because $b_1, \ldots, b_n$ are linearly independent, you get the $\alpha_i = 0$. By the way, if you like my answer, consider upvoting it or accepting it on the top left corner of the answer.

Comment: Ah. Got it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If a linear transformation $T$ is injective, then $\ker(T)=\{0\}$. Applying the rank-nullity theorem, the rank of $T$ is exactly $\dim(V)$. The only full-dimensional subspace of a vector space $V$ is $V$ itself, thus $T$ is surjective as well.

Answer (score 0):

$R(T)\subseteq V$ is a subspace of $V$ that means

$\dim R(T) \leq \dim V$

Assume $T$ is not bijective we want to show  $\dim R(T) < \dim V$

$T$ is not bijective so there are $v_1 \neq v_2$ in $V$ and $T(v_1)= T(v_2)$

$\Rightarrow T(v_1-v_2)=0\Rightarrow \ker T\neq \{0\}\Rightarrow \dim (\ker T)\geq 0$

Now because $\dim(\ker T)+\dim(Im(T)) = \dim(V)$

It follows that $\dim (Im(T))< \dim(V)$

Which means $R(T)=Im(T)\neq V$

Contradiction to the fact $T$ is injective